# Rails: Use livereload with Asset Pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sass, asset-pipeline

Quick question for rails pros out there...

When working with Rails 3.0.x apps I was a heavy user of Guard and LiveReload. However, it seems that when using the asset pipeline in Rails 3.1 the livereload guard does not know that changes to a Sass file should trigger sending new css to the browser.

Is anyone using LiveReload with the Asset Pipeline? If so, how are you making it work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After following some issue threads on Github I found the following fixed my problem:

1) Make sure all scss files are named following the new asset convention, like so: `filename.css.scss`

I was using scss before Rails 3.1 and had just named all my sass files `filename.scss`.

2) Use the following for livereload in your guardfile:

```
guard 'livereload' do
  watch(%r{app/helpers/.+\.rb})
  watch(%r{app/views/.+\.(erb|haml)})
  watch(%r{(public/).+\.(css|js|html)})
  watch(%r{app/assets/stylesheets/(.+\.css).*$})    { |m| "assets/#{m[1]}" }
  watch(%r{app/assets/javascripts/(.+\.js).*$}) { |m| "assets/#{m[1]}" }
  watch(%r{lib/assets/stylesheets/(.+\.css).*$})    { |m| "assets/#{m[1]}" }
  watch(%r{lib/assets/javascripts/(.+\.js).*$}) { |m| "assets/#{m[1]}" }
  watch(%r{vendor/assets/stylesheets/(.+\.css).*$}) { |m| "assets/#{m[1]}" }
  watch(%r{vendor/assets/javascripts/(.+\.js).*$})  { |m| "assets/#{m[1]}" }
  watch(%r{config/locales/.+\.yml})
end
```

Comment: nice, I had forgotten about the lib folder. Would you bother throwing the vendor directory in there too?

Comment: Sure, vendor directory added.

Comment: Make sure you have the guard-livereload gem in your GemFile.

Comment: Extra .css in SCSS file is now deprecated and Sprockets4 will not support it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27537437/upgraded-to-scss-rails-gem-gives-deprecation-warning
so there is no way to inject sass without full refresh for now...

Answer (score 6):

I have found the following to work quite well too:

```
guard :livereload do
  watch(%r{^app/.+\.(erb|haml|js|css|scss|sass|coffee|eco|png|gif|jpg)})
  watch(%r{^app/helpers/.+\.rb})
  watch(%r{^public/.+\.html})
  watch(%r{^config/locales/.+\.yml})
end
```

This is not the default code that is generated when you run `guard init livereload` as for some reason that does not work so well with sass imports.

Comment: Yes if you are using SASS correctly you don't want your partials compiled to css so you can't name them *.css.scss.

Comment: I posted this related question for clarification of this point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12334515/naming-imported-scss-files-scss-or-css-scss. So if you have file named _file.scss and it's used in @import "file";, then this strategy for livereload is the right one and these files should not be renamed to _file.css.scss.

Comment: Yes! This helped me more than any other example. I'm using the asset pipeline combined with a SCSS include system. You example worked "out of the box" for me.

Answer (score 2):

As @mirko mentioned in his comment, extra .css on scss files is deprecated. So adding that isn't a great solution, and I've experienced that simply adding the scss extension forces a page reload.

So I found that this works:

```
watch(%r{(app|vendor)(/assets/\w+/(.+)\.(scss))}) { |m| "/assets/#{m[3]}.css" }`
```

My understanding is this maps the scss file to the compiled css file. I hope it works for sass too.

[Source: Github Issue](https://github.com/guard/guard-livereload/issues/126#issuecomment-72420391)