# upgrade sass-rails gem to 5.0 gives deprecation warning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, asset-pipeline

We upgraded to sass-rails version 5.0.0 and are getting this deprecation warning:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Extra .css in SCSS file is unnecessary. Rename /Users/foo/Projects/foo/app/assets/stylesheets/foo.css.scss to /Users/foo/Projects/foo/app/assets/stylesheets/foo.scss. (called from _app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__1560597815210891605_70190441246060 at /Users/foo/Projects/foo/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:13)
```

Anyone know whats going on with this?  Does the gem really want me to rename all of my stylesheet assets from:

```
app/assets/stylesheets/foo.css.scss
```

to:

```
app/assets/stylesheets/foo.scss
```

?

Seems to run against years of Rails convention to me.  Perhaps there is a way to suppress the deprecation warning?

Comment: Seems like there was back and forth here: https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/commit/bac031b802f785cfc3d3b561617b0f7bd64d78ba. You could always overwrite it (such as in an initializer), if you prefer.

Comment: Discussion here: https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/issues/290

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes you need to rename your `.css.scss` to just `.scss`, as `.css.scss` will not be supported in sprockets 4.

If you want to suppress the deprecation temporary you can the following to `config/initializer/deprecations.rb`

```
Rails.application.config.after_initialize do
  old_behaviour = ActiveSupport::Deprecation.behavior
  ActiveSupport::Deprecation.behavior = ->(message, callstack) {
    unless message.starts_with?('DEPRECATION WARNING: Extra .css in SCSS file is unnecessary.',
                                'DEPRECATION WARNING: Extra .css in SASS file is unnecessary.')
      old_behaviour.each { |behavior| behavior[message,callstack] }
    end
  }
end
```

Or you can monkey patch to not to generate the message like this:

```
module DisableCssDeprecation
  def deprecate_extra_css_extension(engine)
    if engine && filename = engine.options[:filename]
      if filename.end_with?('.css.scss','.css.sass')
        engine
      else
        super
      end 
    end
  end
end

module Sass ; module Rails ; class SassImporter
  prepend DisableCssDeprecation
end ; end ; end
```

Answer (score 32):

This handled it for me:

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in $(find ./app/assets/stylesheets/ -name "*.css.scss")
do
    git mv $file `echo $file | sed s/\.css//`
done
```

Comment: Extra help: Save that to a file (something like `remove_css_extension.sh`), `$ chmod a+x remove_css_extension.sh`, `$ ./remove_css_extension.sh`, done.

Comment: Instead of sed just use basename: `git mv "$file" $(basename "$file" .scss)`

Comment: Didn't know about basename. Nice!

Comment: I used your script together with this find command to loop through both sass and scss files in all the subfolders (I also had some in ./vendor/assets): `find ./ -name "*.css.scss" -o -name "*.css.sass"`

Answer (score 1):

This command helped me renaming lots of .css.sass files:

```
find ./app/assets/stylesheets -type f | sed 'p;s/\.css\.scss/.scss/' | xargs -n2 git mv
```