# Livereload on Rails not showing SCSS changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sass, livereload

I have the following setup: rails 4. all SCSS and HTML are in `app/assets/stylesheets | templates`

Gemfile:

```
gem 'guard'
gem 'guard-compass'
gem 'guard-shell'
gem 'guard-livereload'
```

Guardfile:

```
guard :livereload do
  watch(%r{app/assets/.+\.(css|html|png|jpg)})
end
```

Liverload is connected and waiting for changes

```
$ guard
19:45:10 - INFO - LiveReload is waiting for a browser to connect.
19:45:11 - INFO - Guard is now watching at '/Users/dev/myproject'
[1] guard(main)> 19:46:05 - INFO - Browser connected.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails: Use livereload with Asset Pipeline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031880/rails-use-livereload-with-asset-pipeline)

Answer (score 3):

I'm having the same issue -- I think it's because Guard only watches for CSS changes, but the CSS isn't compiled until a request is made. If you edit your main stylesheet (or any with the `.css.scss` extension) should trigger a live-reload although partials won't. 
Adding `scss` to your guardfile should mean it picks up changes in partials, but it seems to trigger a full page refresh rather than injecting the styles.

I assume this is a misconfiguration on my part or possibly an update to one of the gems has broken something but I'm not sure how to begin tracking that down.